# NPM error: "npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY" when installing react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router-dom, npm-install

When I run `npm i -S react-router-dom@latest`,

I get the following errors:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/albertnt/my-portfolio/my-portfolio/node_modules/acorn-globals
npm ERR! dest /Users/albertnt/my-portfolio/my-portfolio/node_modules/.acorn-globals-zFzwhPtP
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/albertnt/my-portfolio/my-portfolio/node_modules/acorn-globals' -> '/Users/albertnt/my-portfolio/my-portfolio/node_modules/.acorn-globals-zFzwhPtP'
```

What should I do to fix it? I can't give `react-router-dom` to work and it gives me an invalid hook error when I try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the package-lock.json and node-modules folder. Then add react-router-dom: "6.3.0" or whatever version you would like to the package.json if it isn't already there.

I uninstalled react-router dom globally as well,

Then restart your IDE and npm install in the terminal